# python用milkcocoaのSDKがインストールできない。

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, milkcocoa

Raspberry pi3につけたセンサーのデータをmilkcocoaに転送したいと思い、
python SDKをインストールしようと思い、以下のようにしましたが、エラーがでてます。
解決方法を教えてください。

https://github.com/milk-cocoa/python_sdk
からmilkcocoaのpython用のSDKをダウンロードしてきてsetup.pyを以下のように修正して、

$ sudo python3 setup.py install

としましたが、"Install pip in your computer"とでます。
※pip3,python3はwhereで存在していることは確認済。

OS:Ubuntu mate16.04
Hard: Raspberry PI3 B

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from __future__ import print_function
from setuptools import setup
try:
#    from pip.req import parse_requirements
    from pip3.req import parse_requirements
except ImportError:
    print('Install pip in your computer')
    exit(1)

from milkcocoa import __version__ as version


def get_packages():
    import os

    req_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'requirements.txt')
    if not os.path.isfile(req_path):
        raise OSError(req_path + 'file not found in project directory')

    requirements = parse_requirements(filename=req_path, session=False)
    requirements = [requirement.req.project_name for requirement in requirements]

    return requirements

setup(
    name='milkcocoa-python-sdk',
    version=version,
    install_requires=get_packages(),
    packages=['milkcocoa']
```

Answer (score 1):

解決しましたので自己レスです。

```
try:
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
#    from pip3.req import parse_requirements
```

とやっても以下のエラーがでたままでした。

```
  File "setup.py", line 31, in <module>
    install_requires=get_packages(),
  File "setup.py", line 23, in get_packages
    requirements = [requirement.req.project_name for requirement in requirements]
  File "setup.py", line 23, in <listcomp>
    requirements = [requirement.req.project_name for requirement in requirements]
AttributeError: 'Requirement' object has no attribute 'project_name
```

いろいろ調べたところ以下の2つの対応でエラーがなくなりました。

1.足りないパッケージのインストール
`$ sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

2.project_nameをnameに変更

```
#requirements = [requirement.req.project_name for requirement in
requirements]
requirements = [requirement.req.name for requirement in requirements]
```